# Selecting any one of the IDs of duplicate values to get only unique columns from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, unique, distinct

I have a website with products where some products are duplicated, and the duplication is only because sometimes the same products goes under more than one `categories`. I just want the unique columns of the `product`, not the duplicate (that has another ID and another `Category_id`). I know the problem could be solved if the table was normalized, but I didn't develop these tables and I can't redesign the database now.

So basically I'm trying to something that logically looks like this (but the code below still gets the repeated products):

```
SELECT id
FROM `website_products`
WHERE p_name_en
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT p_name_en
FROM `website_products`
)
```

Comment: what are the column names of the table?

Comment: please provide your table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want:

```
select distinct id
from website_products
```

Or are you trying to get distinct product names with a single id:

```
select p_name_en, id
from website_products wp
group by p_name_en;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try like this,,,

```
SELECT id
FROM `website_products
group by p_name_en
```